# Connecting Panels with Views

Tags: views, panels, entities

Forgive the obtuse explanation.

I have a content type, called SHOW. this show type has a title and client and supervisor and a number of other fields associated with it.

I have an employee of the company fill out the SHOW information on the website. then, this information is available to all employees - it's an intranet.

I have another content type. It's called REQUEST. The first field in this form is a relate-able auto complete list of the SHOW titles that have been created on our site. This content type has some other fields as well, none that are related to anything else.

I have a panel that displays pertinent information from a show, the stuff I want like title and some of the other fields. All is good. In panels I've overridden the node panel for this content type to do this.

Now here's my problem.

I created a view as a table to show the REQUEST content types. I want to show this view in the SHOW panel. I've managed to do this. BUT, i only want to show the view for the corresponding SHOW that I'm in the panel for. I have 3 shows (these are TV shot titles) and each show has like 6 REQUEST content types filled out for it. Again, I only want to show this view on this panel for this specific show.

I'm so lost. Can anyone help?

Comment: I suggest you would try to isolate the exact functionality you want and edit the question with a more shorter\specific explanation about it.

Comment: I agree with @Benia we don't need all the mumbo jumbo, kinda confusing.

Comment: Sorry guys, I often get dinged for not adding enough context - and in this case I thought it was important.

Answer (score 0):

In your view settings, sound like you just need to (under Advanced) add a CONTEXTUAL filter of Nid and use Content ID from URL.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, i think this is closer to what I'm after. But won't the content ID change. These requests that are filled out are many, and I want to associate the view to another content type. The things these two share are the SHOW TITLE

Comment: For testing purposes, you can change type to fix then put a nid of one of your SHOW nodes. Which will show your SHOW node, but then you need to add a RELANTIONSHIP of Refereced entity, and once you do that, it will show your REQUEST nodes that are associatted with your SHOW nid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question but a key thing to do when using panels and views is to add a views content pane and then add arguments from Context in the view settings. It's in the middle of the settings above "allow settings". Any node contextual filters won't work without that.